# How to hide YouTube video after it ends using googleapis package?

Tags: youtube-api, dart

I want to operate with googleapis package. I want simply to hide a YouTube video after it ends. I have the following code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:googleapis/youtube/v3.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(r'''
{
  "private_key_id": ...,
  "private_key": ...,
  "client_email": ...,
  "client_id": ...,
  "type": "service_account"
}
''');

const _SCOPES = const [StorageApi.DevstorageReadOnlyScope];

main(){
// insert stylesheet for video (width, height, border, etc.) - works well
LinkElement styles=new LinkElement();
styles..href='iframe.css'
     ..rel='stylesheet'
     ..type='text/css';
document.head.append(styles);

//add iframe element - works also well
IFrameElement video=new IFrameElement();
video.attributes={'allowfullscreen':'','seamless':'','src':'http://www.youtube.com/embed/ORsFFjt1x6Q?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1'};
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('afterBegin',video);

//check if the video has ended - probably doesn't work
if(video.contentDocument.onLoad){
if(video.getPlayerState==0){
video.remove();
}
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are trying almost correctly. Maybe you should try to change how you load video and then onStateChange event you can close the video

Comment: I'll try and we'll see

Answer (score 0):

Your `video` variable is type of IFrameElement and you can't run callMethod of JsObject on it.
You need to use Youtube API of Dart which is in Beta from Google and is deprecated in Dart document.

Dart has an `onEnded` event method for IFrameElement, Element and MediaElement which is in experimental yet but may work for you.

I suggest to use YouTube iframe JavaScript API in your Dart code!

these sources explain what you need:

1. https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/
2. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

if you need more information tell me what you want to know.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, I could change this: `if(video.contentDocument.onLoad){
if(video.getPlayerState==0){
video.remove();
}}` to this: `if(video.contentDocument.onLoad){
if(video.onEnded){
video.remove();
}}` to make it work?

Comment: No! Please read references which I mentioned... You need to use JS version of YouTube  API in your Dart.

Comment: Sorry, I thought, that I could avoid using JS interop by using googleapis somehow.